# How do i give a unique data id to custom buttons in a fancybox with dyamically added content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fancybox

i have a fancy box to which i have added two custom buttons: a like and dislike button. since images are added dynamically to the fancybox, how do i bind the instance image_id to the like and dislike buttons?

```
//a while loop populates the fancybox   
<a href="<?php echo $imgpath; ?>" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $imgdesc; ?>"  data-img="<?php echo $imgid;?>"
    data-user_id="<?php  echo $user_id?>" class="fancybox">
        <img src="<?php echo $imgpath; ?>" alt="<?php echo $imgdesc; ?>" />

    </a>
```

i would like to pass the image_id from the php side to the like and dislike buttons added below
adding like  and dislike button to fancybox

```
   $.fancybox.defaults.btnTpl.like = '<button data-fancybox-like class=" fa fa- thumbs-  o-up   fancybox-button fancybox-button--like" title="like"></button>';
   $.fancybox.defaults.btnTpl.dislike = '<button data-fancybox-dislike class=" fa fa-thumbs-o-down   fancybox-button fancybox-button--dislike" title="dislike"></button>';

   $.fancybox.defaults.buttons = [
    'slideShow',
    'fullScreen',
    'thumbs',
    'like', // the new  like button
    'dislike',//the new dislike button
    'close'];


     

    //getting instance of the clicked like button

    $('body').on('click', '[data-fancybox-like]', function(e) {
 var imgid =$.fancybox.getInstance().current.opts.$orig.data('img')
 var userr=$.fancybox.getInstance().current.opts.$orig.data('user_id');
 $clicked_btn=$("[data-liky='"+imgid+"']");
 
if ($clicked_btn.hasClass('fa-thumbs-o-up')) {//checking if php had marked the like button as unliked
                     reaction = 'like';
              } else if($clicked_btn.hasClass('fa-thumbs-up')){//the like button had already been liked. liking again unlikes
                        reaction = 'unlike';      
              }
              //change this to the full ajax format
                $.ajax({
                  url:"server.php",
                  method:'POST',
                  data:{reaction:reaction,imgid:imgid,user:user},
                  success:function(data,status){}
```

The code works fine. the problem is the like and dislike buttons do not have a dynamic id

Comment: It sounds like mapping should be able to do what you need. Search up how to map DOM elements with vanilla JS.

Comment: Thank you so much. lemmi have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give such a unique id to those buttons.

On click, you already can check if it is the like or unlike button... And you already have the `imgid` and `user`.

```js
$.fancybox.defaults.btnTpl.like =
  '<button data-fancybox-like class="fas fa-thumbs-up fancybox-button fancybox-button--like" title="like"></button>';
$.fancybox.defaults.btnTpl.dislike =
  '<button data-fancybox-dislike class="fas fa-thumbs-down fancybox-button fancybox-button--dislike" title="dislike"></button>';

$.fancybox.defaults.buttons = [
  "slideShow",
  "fullScreen",
  "thumbs",
  "like", // the new  like button
  "dislike", //the new dislike button
  "close"
];

//getting instance of the clicked like button

$("body").on("click", "[data-fancybox-like], [data-fancybox-dislike]", function (e) {
  
  var imgid = $.fancybox.getInstance().current.opts.$orig.data("img");
  var user = $.fancybox.getInstance().current.opts.$orig.data("user_id");
  var reaction
  // $clicked_btn = $("[data-liky='" + imgid + "']");

  if ($(this).hasClass("fa-thumbs-up")) {
    //checking if php had marked the like button as unliked
    reaction = "like";
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("fa-thumbs-down")) {
    //the like button had already been liked. liking again unlikes
    reaction = "unlike";
  }
  
  console.log(reaction, "imgid:", imgid, "user:", user)
  //change this to the full ajax format
  // $.ajax({
  //   url: "server.php",
  //   method: "POST",
  //   data: { reaction: reaction, imgid: imgid, user: user },
  //   success: function (data, status) {}
  // });
});
```

```css
/* Just for this demo */
.as-console-wrapper{
  max-height: 1.2em !important;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>


<a href="https://via.placeholder.com/150" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Some caption 1" data-img="54" data-user_id="12" class="fancybox">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Some descrition 1" />
</a>

<a href="https://via.placeholder.com/150" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Some caption 2" data-img="72" data-user_id="28" class="fancybox">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Some descrition 2" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is impressive. but my issue is, I would love to have various instances of the same button. so that if the user moves to the next image, the buttons won't be styled as if they had been reacted to. I need to change their colors depending on either likes or dislike. So  i intend to bind the image_id to the buttons instantaneously .Thank you in advance.

Comment: The thing is that button does not re-render on image next/prev. FancyBox is not made like this. You will have to change the style of the icon dynamically based on prev/next. And you need to store the states somewhere.

Comment: any  idea how i can do this? would really be helpful. I`d really like to know how i can change the style of these buttons when the prev or next button is clicked